# How to implement Close Trade or Close Position with QuickfixJ

Tags: java, quickfix, fix-protocol

I am not really sure how to implement Close Trade or Close Position with QuickFIXJ. Is it possible?

Comment: This is pretty vague. Can you provide more detail on what you're trying to do, and in what context you're trying to do it?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like even *you* don't know what you're asking.  But let's see if I can help.

FIX doesn't tell you how to trade.  FIX merely specifies a communication protocol, and provides a bunch of messages and fields that parties can choose to use.

However, **and this is important**, that set of default messages and fields are best treated as suggestions.  No counterparty uses *all* of those messages, and no counterparty uses *all* fields in a message.  Heck, nearly every party I've worked with customizes messages by adding or removing fields.

Thus, the right answer to your question is dependent on what your counterparty wants to see.  They will tell you how they want you to close a trade, or close a position.  They may not even support such actions.

So, find your counterparty's specs (they should have them), and read them closely.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about "cancel and amend" for an open order?